# Next.js Image placeholder blururl with placeholder not understanding

Tags: reactjs, next.js, placeholder

I'll try and explain this as well as I can. I am wanting to use placeholder to implement a placeholder image for the next `<Images/>` loading in. However, my images are dynamic and there are quite a number of them. How would I implement something that goes well with what I have.

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from '@/styles/films/film.module.css'
import { Breadcrumbs } from '@mui/material'
import Link from 'next/link';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Profile_Image from '@/components/Profile_image';
import Rating from '@mui/material/Rating';
import Image from 'next/image';


export async function generateMetadata({ searchParams }) {
  const film = searchParams.film

  return {
    title: `${film} - TRDB`,
  }
}

async function getData(filmID) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${filmID}?api_key=key`
    )
  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
  return res.json()
}

async function getCredits(filmID) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${filmID}/credits?api_key=key`
    )
  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
  return res.json()
}

export default async function Page({ params, searchParams }) {
  const filmID = params.filmID
  const dataData = getData(filmID)
  const creditsData = getCredits(filmID)

  const [data, credits] = await Promise.all([dataData, creditsData])

  const year = data.release_date.substring(0, data.release_date.length - 6)

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
        <div className={styles.page}>
          <div className={styles.navigation}>
            <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb" sx={{
              "& ol": {
                justifyContent: "center",
                margin: "auto"
              }
            }}>
              <Link className={styles.breadcrumbs_link} href={'/'}>
                Home
              </Link>
              <Link className={styles.breadcrumbs_link} href={'/films'}>
                Films
              </Link>
              <Typography color="grey">{searchParams.film}</Typography>
            </Breadcrumbs>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.show}>
            <div className={styles.image_container}>
              <Image src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${data.poster_path}`}
              alt={`${data.name}`}
              className={styles.show_image}
              layout='responsive'
              width='600'
              height='900'
              ></Image>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.film_info}>
              <h1>
                {data.title}: ({year})
              </h1>
              <div className={styles.rating}>
                <p>TMDB Rating: </p>
                <Rating sx={{display: 'flex'}}
                precision={0.1}
                defaultValue={data.vote_average / 2}
                name="half-rating-read"
                readOnly />
                <p>{(data.vote_average).toFixed(1) * 10}%</p>
              </div>
              <p>
                Release Date: {data.release_date}
              </p>
              <p>
                Description: {data.overview}
              </p>
              <div>
                <p>Cast</p>
                <br></br>
                <div className={styles.actors}>
                  {credits.cast.map((actors, index) => (
                    <div className={styles.profile} key={index}>
                      <Profile_Image 
                        className={styles.season_grid_item_image}
                        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${actors.profile_path}`}
                        alt={`${actors.name}`}
                        width='120'
                        height='160'
                        name={actors.name}
                      ></Profile_Image>
                      <p>{actors.character} / {actors.name}</p>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>Crew</p>
                <br></br>
                <div className={styles.actors}>
                  {credits.crew.map((crew, index) => (
                    <div className={styles.profile} key={index}>
                      <Profile_Image 
                        className={styles.season_grid_item_image}
                        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${crew.profile_path}`}
                        alt={`${crew.name}`}
                        width='120'
                        height='160'
                        name={crew.name}
                      ></Profile_Image>
                      <p>{crew.job} / {crew.name}</p>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

This was the smallest code snippit I had. If some documentation that helps explain it better is all anyone has then great, but no one seems to have made any kind of guide or anything I seem to be able to follow. I am using next 13 with the app router, if that helps explain the code better